# Should we use br, hr tags in our HTML code?

Tags: html

I was been told by a  colleague of mine that instead of using the br tag we could we could use a span tag and give it a display:block  and for the hr tag we could do it with the after pseudo element using css. I have been told that this was a good practice to follow  than using these html tags. Is it true for these two cases that this way is preferred over the others or could we use it these two tags itself ?

Comment: If using `<br />` and `<hr>` is a bad practice, They would have deprecated those tags already, don't you think?

Comment: _"I have been told that this was a good practice"_ - and why did you not ask for the reasoning behind that statement there and then?

Comment: Plus, even typing your question title into Google verbatim could have easily lead you to https://line25.com/articles/youre-doing-it-wrong-common-html-tag-misuse already ... #makeaneffort

Answer (score 3):

native html elements are ALWAYS better to use than other weird way to do the same things. The most often, if people don't use `<br>` and `<hr>` tags, it's because it doesn't fit the graphic needs.

By the way, creating an `<span>` tag, just to make a space between two blocks is a horrible way to do it. Use css, even with style !

Answer (score 1):

I would not use `<br>` for layouting, but only for breaking text mid-paragraph. Still would prefer multiple paragraphs if possible. Instead I would use margins to separate blocks.

On top of @kevinniel's answer, seems like a bad idea to use a `<span>` (natural inline element) just to change it to a block element (which is the default for `<div>`'s).